# No database selected when trying to setup query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i get the following error "No database selected" when trying to run a query in php. the connect file in in the connect.inc.php file and that returns no error. i an learning php so any help i thank you. Also to note the query works in phpmyadmin panel with no errors

```
<?php

require 'connect.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT `name`, `address`, `city` FROM `customers` ORDER BY `id`";

if ($sql_run = mysql_query($sql)) {

echo 'Success.';
} else {
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: Either use `mysql_select_db()`, or `SELECT ... FROM dbname.customers`.

Comment: Start with a better tutorial

Comment: Need to see the contents of `connect.inc.php`

Comment: 'better' as in 'a little more up-to-date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use in your `connect.inc.php` the [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function just after `mysql_connect`:

```
mysql_select_db('your_database_name');
```

or add the database name in every query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`, `address`, `city` FROM `your_database_name`.`customers` ORDER BY `id`";
```

**Note that the `mysql` library is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and you should use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).** If you're learning, run away from any "tutorial" that still uses these deprecated functions.

Comment: thank you this worked ($sql = "SELECT `name`, `address`, `city` FROM `your_database_name`.`customers` ORDER BY `id`";)

Answer (score 1):

**The `mysql` library is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).**

With `mysqli`, you can also select the database directly when you're creating the connection (and I recommend doing that when possible, if you're only working with one database) :

```
$db = mysqli_connect("<host>","<username>","<password>","<database>");
```

Replace `<database>` with the DB you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

hope you write write script to connect DB in this way or you can try this....

```
$connection = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpass");
if (!$connection)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Connected";

    $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("$dbname");
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database '" . $database . "'</p>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted for promoting deprecated functions and pasting a horrible code block with no explanation. mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score -2):

This is a basic example i have kind of filled in with your code. You will need to fill in the vars with FILL THIS as values.

```
<?php
$host = "FILL THIS";
$db = "FILL THIS";
$user = "FILL THIS";
$pass = "FILL THIS";
$link = mysql_connect($host,$user ,$pass);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error());
}
require 'connect.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT `name`, `address`, `city` FROM `customers` ORDER BY `id`";

if ($sql_run = mysql_query($sql,$link)) {

echo 'Success.';
} else {
echo mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($link); 

?>
```

Comment: This just perpetuates the tired old methods we're trying so hard to deprecate